# how to set custom text in react-native webview on focused field

Tags: react-native

The WebView##

---

## of react-native does not have property to find the currently active Element id to change the current state of container.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use WebView's [injectJavascript](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#injectjavascript) function

An example of selecting the element id of a div and change the text:

```
class WebView extends Component{
    focusOnDiv() {
        this.webView.injectJavascript(`
            var textField = document.getElementById("text-field");
            textField.textContent = "New content";
        `);
    }
    render() {
        <WebView ref={webView => this.webView = webView}/>
    }
}
```